# HTML select always posts first option when form is submitted

Tags: php, forms, html-select

I have the simplest possible form, with one select with 3 options and a submit button. The problem is that when I click the submit button the selection in the select element, returns to the first option. And when I do the var dump of POST variable on the page that is the form handler, I get the string that is the first option. Why is this happening? What do I need to do? I have a bootstrap modal window on another page, with two select elements and it works fine there?

Here is the html code:

```
   <form class="navbar-form navbar-center" method = "POST" action="sortiranje.php"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <select class="cities typeahead form-control" id="kriterijum" name="kriterijumSortiranja">
   <option value=""></option>
   <option value="CenaR">Cena rastuće</option>
   <option value="CenaO">Cena opadajuće</option>
   <option value="Tip">Tip</option>
  </select>
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn">Sortiraj</button>
```

And in sortiranje.php there is only:

```
<?php 
var_dump($_POST['kriterijumSortiranja']);
?>
```

And the result is:
string '' (length=0)

Comment: You need to show your PHP also.

Comment: I've added it, but I don't think that php is the problem.

Comment: You need to do `$kriterijumSortiranja=$_POST['kriterijumSortiranja'];` then `echo $kriterijumSortiranja;` or shorter form `$var=$_POST['kriterijumSortiranja'];` then `echo $var;` therefore, reason being is that you didn't assign a variable to it.

Comment: I've just tried that, but it's still the same. The problem is that the first option:  <option value=""></option>, always gets selected when I click the submit button.

Comment: Wait a minute, I tested your code and it checks out. Are you sure this is the actual code you're using? I got back `string(5) "CenaR"` and `string(5) "CenaO"` and `string(3) "Tip"`

Comment: @Matija i tested your code and it works fine on my side.

Comment: Your select has class name "typeahead", does this mean there is some JavaScript stuff attached to it? Try removing the JavaScript and see if the problem remains.

Comment: @miken32
Yes, the "typeahead" part was the problem, I forgot to delete it, although it shouldn't make a problem, but nevermind it works fine now. Thank you all for your answers. :)

Comment: You're welcome. `Another Happy Ending`